# Image magick, prevent outside-overlay from happening when using fill on multiple images

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

So i'm using ImageMagick convert to overlay multiple pictures on top of each other using a for loop in PHP. The problem is in the convert command, since i'm trying to add white fill to specific images. The line looks like this

```
while(pics) { //this is just pseudo code for the loop since the loop works
    convert pic.jpg  -fill white -colorize 50% -geometry +x +y -composite  result.png
    }
```

This adds pictures on top of each other, but the fill is preserved only for the last one, since any new time I add the fill it overlays the other pictures as well. I've tried stopping this with

```
convert pic.jpg  -fill white -colorize 50% -geometry +x +y -composite  outside-overlay=false result.png
```

But this doesn't work at all. What am I doing wrong, am I typing the command wrong or my reasoning is bad?

Comment: Please give a sensible example as I don't understand what you are trying to do. You cannot use `-composite` with just a single image. Where did you get `outside-overlay=false` from? How do the before and after images actually look?

Comment: sorry I meant 
convert pic.jpg pic2.jpg  -fill white -colorize 50% -geometry +x +y -composite  outside-overlay=false result.png. I can't post actual examples since I'm working with sensitive material. What I meant is I am trying to composite several pictures on top of pic1. I am using for loop to repeat same statements but change pictures. I set colorize to only some pictures but the last picture in the loop always makes entire collection faded, because it overlays outside of given zone
command I'm talking about:
https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#composite

Comment: Your command is colorizing both input pic.jpg and pic2.jpg with 50% white. Is that what you really want to do? I do not understand how this relates to color outside the image bounds. I do not know of any command "outside-overlay=false"? Where did you get that? If looks like a -define, but I do not see any -define on that section of the options documentation. Do you have a reference to "outside-overlay=false"? Are your two input images always the same size?

Comment: Okay let me try again. Lets say I have these 3 lines
convert pic1.jpg pic72.jpg -fill white -colorize 50% -geometry +x +y -composite
convert pic1.jpg pic73.jpg -fill white -colorize 30% -geometry +x +y -composite
convert pic1.jpg pic74.jpg -fill white -colorize 70% -geometry +x +y -composite

The last line will make the entire resulting image to have 70% fill. I do not want that, I want append pictures on top of each other, where every picture that I am appending has it's own fill percentage. I hope I am clearer now

Comment: for example if I do it on 2 pics, I would want it to look like this 
https://snag.gy/oJ5OaI.jpg

But when I put that 2nd fill on the koala for example, I get this 
https://snag.gy/CU37Pi.jpg